# Обособление оборотов с КАК.., ТАК И...

Tags: пунктуация

Это может привести как к увеличению, так и снижению КПД (,) в зависимости от расположения рабочей точки по отношению к точке оптимального КПД для рабочего колеса максимального диаметра.

Нужна ли здесь запятая после "КПД"? Знаю, что обороты с КАК... ТАК И... обособляются, но нужно ли закрывать этот оборот запятой? Или на постановку этой запятой влияют какие-то другие факторы?

Comment: Обратите внимание: правильно "КАК К увеличению, ТАК И К снижению".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это может привести как к увеличению, так и снижению КПД  в зависимости от расположения рабочей точки по отношению к точке оптимального КПД для рабочего колеса максимального диаметра.

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ

1) Двойной союз КАК...ТАК И соединяет однородные члены (не обособленные), поэтому запятая после второго однородного члена не ставится.

Пример: Все окна как в барском доме, так и в людских отворены настежь. Сравнить: Все окна и в барском доме, и в людских отворены настежь.

2) Обстоятельственный оборот не обособляется, так как входит в основное сообщение и находится в конце предложения.

Но в начале предложения возможно обособление такого оборота в связи с его распространенностью:

В зависимости от расположения рабочей точки по отношению к точке оптимального КПД для рабочего колеса максимального диаметра, это может привести как к увеличению, так и снижению КПД.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Значит то, что это обстоятельственный оборот, здесь значения не имеет и играет роль его расположение? А если предложение построено так: Это может как повысить, так и понизить КПД, в зависимости от расположения рабочей точки относительно точки оптимального КПД для рабочего колеса максимального диаметра?

Comment: В принципе постановка запятой возможна, так как оборот распространенный, обычно обособление обстоятельственных оборотов факультативно, делается с учетом влияния разных факторов. В данном случае за обособленность говорить распространенность оборота, а позиция может влиять в меньшей степени