# Знаки препинания при конструкции "как...так и"

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, как

Правильно ли я расставила знаки в следующем предложении?

**Выпуск золотой монеты, как мелкой, так и крупной, постепенно увеличивался.**

Меня волнует уместность постановки запятой перед КАК (остальное мне понятно).

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Обособление оборотов с КАК.., ТАК И...](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/417080/%d0%9e%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-%d1%81-%d0%9a%d0%90%d0%9a-%d0%a2%d0%90%d0%9a-%d0%98)

Answer (score 1):

**Выпуск золотой монеты, как мелкой, так и крупной, постепенно увеличивался.**

Запятая перед КАК в данном предложении нужна, но лишь потому, что в данном случае конструкция "как мелкой, так и крупной", служащая то ли определением, то ли пояснением, стоит после определеямого слова и ее следует выделить запятыми, тире или скобками (Вы выбрали запятые).

Сравните:

**Выпуск как мелкой, так и крупной золотой монеты постепенно увеличивался.**