# «Как для детей, так и для взрослых» — обособление

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, союзы

> В Москве большой выбор бесплатных курсов по рисованию(,) как для детей,
> так и для взрослых!

1. *Как для детей, так и для взрослых* — можно считать это пояснительной конструкцией (*каких курсов?*)? Если да, то запятая перед "как" нужна?
2. А можно запятую перед "как" не ставить?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Обособление оборотов с КАК.., ТАК И...](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/417080/%d0%9e%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-%d1%81-%d0%9a%d0%90%d0%9a-%d0%a2%d0%90%d0%9a-%d0%98)

Comment: Это чего-то не то.

Comment: Я хочу понять, является ли предложение из вопроса таким же, как эти (в них есть запятая перед "КАК"):                                                                                                    
                                             1. Компания признала права Эфиопии на названия ААА, ВВВ и ССС, как охраняемые товарными знаками, так и нет.

2. RFID-метки используются в браслетах для входа на массовые мероприятия, как корпоративные, так и частные.

Comment: Кет, я согласен с Вами, что вопрос по ссылке не соответствует Вашему.

Comment: Ага, спасибо... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нейтральный стиль не хочет запятой:

*В Москве большой выбор бесплатных курсов по рисованию как для детей, так и для взрослых!*

Авторская пауза, приостановка речи допускают и запятую, и тире:

*В Москве большой выбор бесплатных курсов по рисованию, как для детей, так и для взрослых! — В Москве большой выбор бесплатных курсов по рисованию — как для детей, так и для взрослых!*

Comment: 1. Если, допустим, абитуриент в какой-нибудь письменной работе напишет с запятой или тире перед "как", это не посчитают за ошибку? Если посчитают, то может он на апелляции сказать, что прекрасно понимал и понимает, что это составной соединительный союз, соединяющий однородные члены, а поэтому запятая не требуется. Но в его случае знак авторский, поэтому снижать балл комиссия не имеет права. Отстоит абитуриент свою позицию? 2. Допустим, это предложение входит в одно из множества информационных сообщений на официальном школьном сайте. В таком случае от запятой лучше воздержаться?

Comment: Без запятой придраться будет не к чему; тире тоже "красиво", но могут попросить объяснений. Я-то за тире.

Comment: 1. Понятно. Но правильно ли я понимаю, что если поставить запятую или тире (авторские), то конструкция после "как" будет считаться ПОЯСНИТЕЛЬНОЙ? 2. Зарегистрироваться у меня не получается, поэтому на стрелочку "вверх" нажать не могу.

Comment: @Кет 1. Думаю, что на апелляции лучше воздержаться от слов "авторское решение". 2. Союз КАК... ТАК И – сопоставительный, и да – он соединяет однородные члены. 3. В предложениях из вопроса и комментариев конструкция с этим союзом скорее не пояснительная, а присоединительная (дополнительная). Перед ней можно поставить даже точку – структура не останется незаконченной, в отличие от тех предложений, на которых основано основное правило о недопустимости запятой перед КАК. 4. На офиц. школьном сайте запятая или тире тоже допустимы – всё зависит от замысла и логических ударений, то есть от автора :))

Comment: Большое спасибо, Александр!!!

Comment: @Кет Если основная информация заключена в том, что бесплатные курсы по рисованию есть не только для детей, то запятую не ставим и акцент смещается на эту конструкцию. Если мы просто сообщаем, что в Москве есть бесплатные курсы по рисованию, то ставим запятую, а лучше тире (здесь я полностью согласен с Галиной), и дальше добавляем детали.

Comment: Разницу почувствовала :)

Comment: Галина, большое спасибо!!! Тире – действительно самое "красивое" решение!!! :)

Comment: Кэти, мерси! Я редактор, практик, а теорию уже подзабыла, старенькая стала...